# Using objective-c objects with an NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsdictionary

I want store a URL against a UILabel so that when a user touches the label it takes them to that URL in a UIWebView.

I have declared a NSDictionary like so:

```
NSMutableArray *linksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[linksArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject: newsItem1ReadMoreLabel]];
[linksArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject: newsItem2ReadMoreLabel]];
[linksArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject: newsItem3ReadMoreLabel]];
[linksArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject: newsItem4ReadMoreLabel]];
[linksArray addObject: [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject: newsItem5ReadMoreLabel]];
//NSString *ageLink = @"http://www.theage.com.au";
NSArray *defaultLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
self.urlToLinkDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.urlToLinkDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:defaultLinks forKeys:linksArray];
```

Considering I used a `NSValue` as the key, how do I get/set the URL associated with that key given that I only have references to the UILabels?

this is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
for(NSValue *key in [self.urlToLinkDictionary allKeys])
{
    if ([key nonretainedObjectValue] == linkedLabel)
    {
        [self.urlToLinkDictionary setValue:[newsItem link] forKey: key];
    }
}
```

but I get an error: "objc_exception_throw" resolved

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of the error but urlToLinkDictionary is being set using `NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects` in which case the setValue in the loop should fail.  Use `NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects`.  Also, the alloc+init line above the dictionaryWithObjects is not needed and results in a leak.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are the cause of the issue:

```
self.urlToLinkDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.urlToLinkDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:defaultLinks forKeys:linksArray];
```

First you assign a mutable array to the property.  Then you assign a different immutable array to the property.  Your original mutable array leaks because you don't release it.

The exception is being caused by this line:

```
[self.urlToLinkDictionary setValue:[newsItem link] forKey: key];
```

By the time you get to it, self.urlToLinkDictionary is an immutable dictionary.  You can't change it.

There are other problems:

- linksArray leaks because you never release it.
- newsItem1ReadMoreLabel etc.  What type are they?  Why are you wrapping them in values?
- setValue:forKey: is part of key value coding.  On a mutable dictionary it works, but the correct method for accessing objects by keys is setObject:forKey:
- it seems a bit pointless to search a dictionary by doing a linear search through its keys.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a more simplified approach. Associate a tag with every label. The tag is a in integer value and you can use it to locate the url in an array.

So code for creating the array.

```
NSMutableArray* arrayURLs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
newsItem1ReadMoreLabel.tag = 0;
[arrayURLs insertObject:urlStringforLabel1 atIndex:newsItem1ReadMoreLabel.tag];
newsItem2ReadMoreLabel.tag = 1;
[arrayURLs insertObject:urlStringforLabel2 atIndex:newsItem2ReadMoreLabel.tag];
```

then you can access the urlstring for the appropriate label

```
NSString* url = [arrayURLs objectAtIndex:labelClicked.tag];
```